Reducing sound through exterior bedroom doors
We recently moved into a new apartment that has doors out to a porch (no windows, just doors). We are struggling to sleep at night due to living close to a somewhat busy road (in NOVA all roads are busy I guess haha).
I have sealed off the air gaps around the doors with some stripping which has slightly helped and we have gotten a white noise machine which only slightly helped.
I think the vibrations are coming through the window. It’s very thin, old, glass doors.
What are some ideas for reducing the sound coming through? My initial thoughts were to glue some acoustic foam to a sheet of particle board that fits into the doorway.
Some others have suggested theatre curtains (wife really does not want to change curtains but she might if that’s the best idea). What do you all think?
Apartment doors:


We are renters so I’m very hesitant to paint anything on the doors or modify them in anyway.
Thanks

Also: How can I muffle street noise increase from triple-pane windows?

Also many more
